# tabularnewline incompatible with rowcolors

Tags: tables, lyx, color

I have a huge table I am editing with LyX

I tried to use rowcolors to have alternate row colors but it does not work

This looks like to depend on the use of `\tabularnewline`  instead of `\\`

The header column contain multiple lines text (formatted as `p`) so I guess that `\tabularnewline` must be used

How can I obtain alternate row colors with minimum effort?

Sample

```
    %% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.07667em}


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}



\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\noindent \begin{flushleft}
\rowcolors{0}{lightgray}{white}
\begin{tabular*}{2cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\raggedright}m{28mm}|>{\centering}m{14mm}|>{\centering}m{16mm}|>{\centering}m{1.6cm}|>{\centering}m{1.8cm}|>{\centering}m{2cm}|>{\centering}m{1.8cm}|>{\centering}m{1.8cm}|}
\cline{2-8} 
 & {\footnotesize{}1} & {\footnotesize{}2} & {\footnotesize{}3} & {\footnotesize{}4} & {\footnotesize{}5} & {\footnotesize{}6} & {\footnotesize{}7}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-8} 
{\footnotesize{}Aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa } & {\footnotesize{}n/y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-8} 
{\footnotesize{}Bbbbbb bbbbb bbbbb} & {\footnotesize{}n/y} & {\footnotesize{}n/y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-8} 
\end{tabular*}
\par\end{flushleft}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]

The following works:

```
    %% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.07667em}


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}



\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\noindent \begin{flushleft}
\rowcolors{0}{lightgray}{white}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\raggedright}m{28mm}|>{\centering}m{14mm}|>{\centering}m{16mm}|>{\centering}m{1.6cm}|>{\centering}m{1.8cm}|>{\centering}m{2cm}|>{\centering}m{1.8cm}|>{\centering}m{1.8cm}|}
\hline
 & {\footnotesize{}1} & {\footnotesize{}2} & {\footnotesize{}3} & {\footnotesize{}4} & {\footnotesize{}5} & {\footnotesize{}6} & {\footnotesize{}7}\tabularnewline
\hline
{\footnotesize{}Aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa } & {\footnotesize{}n/y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y}\tabularnewline
\hline
{\footnotesize{}Bbbbbb bbbbb bbbbb} & {\footnotesize{}n/y} & {\footnotesize{}n/y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y} & {\footnotesize{}y}\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\par\end{flushleft}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tabularnewline` is just defined by `\let\tabularnewline\\ ` so it should work the same way as `\\ ` If you have an example where it doesn't make a small example document that shows the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: apparently the issue is with cline. but hline was not working with tabular*

Comment: as documented in the `colortbl` package documentation, `\cline` is not compatible with  cell colouring.

Comment: thanks, 
I needed `\cline` because lyx was using `\begin{tabular*}{2cm}` that messed up `\hline`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it appears to be resolved in comments (issues with `\cline` and `colortbl`)